# oracle to ms sql server or database

Tags: sql-server, oracle

can anyone tell me how to access to ms sql database from oracle from another computer?
and i want to know which version of oracle should i use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you need is called [Oracle Transparent Gateway for Microsoft SQL Server](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10544_01/toc.htm) in Oracle 10g. You can only create a DBLINK to another Oracle database out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

The term you need to look up is [DATABASE LINK](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements009.htm#i27761). Check out [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/gencon.htm#sthref353) too